# Why does Windows XP run applications from network shares so much more quickly than Windows 7?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, share

I have multiple clients that run all sorts of (mostly badly-designed) software off network shares. The design of the software is such that it's intended to do so - the server runs the database locally and the clients literally run an executable sitting on a network share.

Without fail, computers that are running WinXP will start this software often instantly, as though the software exists on the XP computer itself, and often run it substantially quicker than the Win7 counterparts, even on better and newer network hardware.

I understand UAC plays a part here, but I don't get elevation requests or anything, so what gives? I'd really like to just understand the why so I can prepare and potentially work around it. I've been given to setting up terminal services so they can remote in and run this software locally, but that's a huge undertaking for what should literally be mapping a network drive and running an executable.

Comment: run process monitor in background while executing the tool and compare the result from XP and Windows 7. Maybe you see anything useful: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Unfortunately I've done everything I can to find out where the holdup is. ProcMon is amazing, but I'm afraid I'm not understanding the output enough to see why a thread has a huge gap between what it's doing right after I launch the program and when the program appears to launch. The consensus seems to be that Windows 7 networking is more advanced than the programs I'm trying to run, which were built in the XP/2000 era and so they aren't supporting that "advanced" networking.